# Isolate Patients with 2 diagnoses but diagnosis data is on different lines

Tags: sas, bioinformatics

I have a dataset of patient data with each diagnosis on a different line.

This is an example of what it looks like:

```
patientID diabetes cancer age gender 
1         1          0     65    M     
1         0          1     65    M     
2         1          1     23    M     
2         0          0     23    M     
3         0          0     50    F     
3         0          0     50    F
```

I need to isolate the patients who have a diagnosis of both diabetes and cancer; their unique patient identifier is patientID. Sometimes they are both on the same line, sometimes they aren't. I am not sure how to do this because the information is on multiple lines.

How would I go about doing this?

This is what I have so far:

```
PROC SQL;
create table want as
select patientID
       , max(diabetes) as diabetes
       , max(cancer) as cancer
       , min(DOB) as DOB
   from diab_dx

   group by patientID;
quit;

data final; set want;
if diabetes GE 1 AND cancer GE 1 THEN both = 1;
else both =0;

run;

proc freq data=final;
tables both;
run;
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Take the MAX of the indicator variables BY PATIENTID.

Comment: The code in the question appears to produce a result that is what you want, so it is already correct.  Are you asking if there are other, more predominant, ways to get the same correct result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to learn about data steps lookup how this works.

```
data pat;
   input patientID diabetes cancer age gender:$1.; 
   cards;
1         1          0     65    M     
1         0          1     65    M     
2         1          1     23    M     
2         0          0     23    M     
3         0          0     50    F     
3         0          0     50    F
;;;;
   run;
data both;
   do until(last.patientid);
      set pat; by patientid;
      _diabetes = max(diabetes,_diabetes);
      _cancer   = max(cancer,_cancer);
      end;
   both = _diabetes and _cancer;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Answer (score 1):

add a having statement at the end of sql query should do.

```
  PROC SQL;
  create table want as
  select patientID
   , max(diabetes) as diabetes
   , max(cancer) as cancer
   , min(age) as DOB
  from PAT

  group by patientID
  having calculated diabetes ge 1 and calculated cancer ge 1;
 quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find some coders, especially those coming from statistical backgrounds, are more likely to use `Proc MEANS` instead of SQL or DATA step to compute the diagnostic flag maximums.

```
proc means noprint data=have;
  by patientID;
  output out=want 
    max(diabetes) = diabetes 
    max(cancer) = cancer
    min(age) = age
  ;
run;
```

or for the case of all the same aggregation function

```
proc means noprint data=have;
  by patientID;
  var diabetes cancer;
  output out=want max=  ;
run;
```

or

```
proc means noprint data=have;
  by patientID;
  var diabetes cancer age; 
  output out=want max= / autoname;
run;
```